# How to use NOT BETWEEN sql syntax in magento collection

Tags: sql, magento, magento-1.9

Can anyone help me to convert the following sql query to magento collection?

```
select * from my_table
where status = 8 and CURDATE() NOT BETWEEN start_date and end_date
group by unit_id
```

I am using flat table, not eav model. I don't know how to use `NOT BETWEEN` syntax in collection.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate function is involved?

Comment: @jarh . I need a distinct unit_id. thats the reason.